Local notification not showing when app is open
I'm trying to have my notification show when my app is in the foreground or background. They are showing when the app is in the background but when I open the app and try to have one show, it doesn't.
I want when my app is open to allow notifications to still show.
watchOSApp.swift
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

@main
struct watchOSApp: App {
    @WKApplicationDelegateAdaptor(WatchDelegate.self) var watchDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


WatchDelegate.swift
import WatchKit
import UserNotifications

class WatchDelegate: NSObject, WKApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        requestNotificationAuthorization()
    }
    
    private func requestNotificationAuthorization() {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
            // Handle the result
            if let error = error {
                print("Error requesting notification authorization: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension WatchDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("willPresent fired from watch delegate")
        
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }
}

Notification code
// Schedule notification
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Exposure complete!"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: Double(exposure), repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error scheduling notification: \(error)")
        }
}

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)


Tell the delegate how. Use the completion handler of the function you already have

@loremipsum Please see updated code, notifications still work when app is in the background but they do not show when in the foreground. userNotificationCenter never is hit as it doesn't ever print anything.

You have to set the delegate too. Look at the link I attached. You want to set it as early as possible
